# GenSA and SA giving nonsense output for Knapsack problem

Tags: r, knapsack-problem

I have the following CSV:

Knapsack.CSV

```
,gewichten(gr),waarde
Voorwerp 1,70,135
Voorwerp 2,73,139
Voorwerp 3,77,149
Voorwerp 4,80,150
Voorwerp 5,82,156
Voorwerp 6,87,163
Voorwerp 7,90,173
Voorwerp 8,94,184
Voorwerp 9,98,192
Voorwerp 10,106,201
Voorwerp 11,110,210
Voorwerp 12,113,214
Voorwerp 13,115,221
Voorwerp 14,118,229
Voorwerp 15,120,240
```

I am trying to solve the Knapsack problem by using GenSA and GA. The solution for this set of data should be around 1458.

However, with this code:

```
install.packages("GenSA")
install.packages("GA")
require(GenSA)
library(GenSA)
require(GA)
library(GA)

#Loading data
df <- read.csv("knapsack.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")


#Define function
knapsack <- function(x) {
  f <- sum(x * df[3])
  penalty <- sum(df[2]) * abs(sum(x*df[2]) - 750)
  f - penalty
}

init <- runif(1, -5000, 5000)

onder <- rep(-5000, length(init))
boven <- rep(5000, length(init)) 



controlelijst <- list(max.time=25, nb.stop.improvement = 100)

resultaatSA <- GenSA(par=init, lower = onder, upper = boven, fn=knapsack, control=controlelijst)

resultaatSA$par




# Solution num 2
SGA <- ga(type="binary", fitness=knapsack, nBits=length(df[1]), maxiter=150, run=250, popSize=100, seed=101)

SGA
SGA@solution
```

I get a lot of nonsense output. GenSA for example says the solution is -5000, or sometimes 5000. Which are boundaries/constraints I have set.

SA gives 1 as solution.

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how do I need to use those two functions correctly?

Comment: The documentation says that GenSA "This function searches for global *minimum*  ..."  are you trying to minimize or maximize the values in the knapsack?

Comment: should `nBits` be  `nBits=NROW(df[1])` to allow items to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

I think John Coleman is correct, and that you have to simply change the sign of your cost function so that it is minimized. Below is a (slightly overkill) example of how this small addition of a minus to your function will result in a very different solution (hopefully the correct one). I have plotted the results in a similar way as `GA` does, as I saw from your code that you were also looking into that as an option (quite a good one in fact). For `GA`, the cost function is *maximized*, so you would need to remove the minus.

```
library(GenSA)
library(GA)

df <- read.table(text = ",gewichten(gr),waarde
Voorwerp 1,70,135
Voorwerp 2,73,139
Voorwerp 3,77,149
Voorwerp 4,80,150
Voorwerp 5,82,156
Voorwerp 6,87,163
Voorwerp 7,90,173
Voorwerp 8,94,184
Voorwerp 9,98,192
Voorwerp 10,106,201
Voorwerp 11,110,210
Voorwerp 12,113,214
Voorwerp 13,115,221
Voorwerp 14,118,229
Voorwerp 15,120,240", sep = ",", header = T
)


#Define function
knapsack <- function(x) {
  f <- sum(x * df[3])
  penalty <- sum(df[2]) * abs(sum(x*df[2]) - 750)
  -(f - penalty) # SIMPLY ADDED A MINUS SIGN
}

init <- runif(1, -5000, 5000)

onder <- rep(-5000, length(init))
boven <- rep(5000, length(init)) 


controlelijst <- list(max.time=25, nb.stop.improvement = 100)

resultaatSA <- GenSA(par=init, lower = onder, upper = boven, fn=knapsack, control=controlelijst)

resultaatSA$par # 0.5233775
head(resultaatSA$trace.mat)


# summarize results
tmp <- as.data.frame(resultaatSA$trace.mat)
meani <- aggregate(tmp$function.value, list(step = tmp$nb.steps),mean, na.rm = TRUE)
exe <- aggregate(tmp$current.minimum, list(step = tmp$nb.steps),mean, na.rm = TRUE)
medi <- aggregate(tmp$function.value, list(step = tmp$nb.steps),median, na.rm = TRUE)
ylim <- c(min(range(exe$x,na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)),
          max(range(meani$x, na.rm = TRUE, finite = TRUE)))

# plot
op <- par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 1, 4.1))
plot(tmp$nb.steps, tmp$function.value, type = "n", ylim = ylim, xlab = "Iteration",
     ylab = "Cost value")
graphics::grid(equilogs = FALSE)
points(tmp$nb.steps, tmp$current.minimum, type = "o", pch = 16, lty = 1,
       col = "green3", cex = 0.7)
points(meani$step, meani$x, type = "o", pch = 1, lty = 2,
       col = "dodgerblue3", cex = 0.7)
polygon(c(meani$step, rev(meani$step)),
        c(exe$x, rev(medi$x)),
        border = FALSE, col = adjustcolor("green3", alpha.f = 0.1))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(tmp$nb.steps, tmp$temperature, t="l", col=2, lty=2, log="y", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4, col=2, col.axis=2); mtext(text = "Temperature", side = 4, line = par()$mgp[1], col=2)
legend("topright", legend = c("Best", "Mean", "Median", "Temperature"),
       col = c("green3", "dodgerblue3", adjustcolor("green3", alpha.f = 0.1), 2),
       pch = c(16, 1, NA, NA), lty = c(1,2,1,2),
       lwd = c(1, 1, 10, 1), pt.cex = c(rep(0.7,2), 2, NA),
       inset = 0.02)
par(op)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the GA call you passed the wrong `nBits` as mentioned in the comment by [user2957945](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957945/user2957945)

Based on: [Solving the Knapsack Problem with a Simple Genetic Algorithm](https://www.dataminingapps.com/2017/03/solving-the-knapsack-problem-with-a-simple-genetic-algorithm/)
<s>I got two solutions with 1449 profit and 750 Weight</s>

**Edit**: with more generations and bigger population size I got one solution with 1456 profit and 750 weight

```
library(GA)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Read Data
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- read.table(text=',gewichten(gr),waarde
Voorwerp 1,70,135
Voorwerp 2,73,139
Voorwerp 3,77,149
Voorwerp 4,80,150
Voorwerp 5,82,156
Voorwerp 6,87,163
Voorwerp 7,90,173
Voorwerp 8,94,184
Voorwerp 9,98,192
Voorwerp 10,106,201
Voorwerp 11,110,210
Voorwerp 12,113,214
Voorwerp 13,115,221
Voorwerp 14,118,229
Voorwerp 15,120,240', sep=',', header=T)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Define  profit, weights, Knapsack limit, and fitness function
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
p <- my_df$waarde
w <- my_df$gewichten.gr.
W <- 750
n <- length(p)

# Define fitness function 
knapsack <- function(x) { 
  f <- sum(x * p) 
  penalty <- sum(w) * abs(sum(x * w) - W) 
  f - penalty 
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run SGA
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
SGA <- ga(type="binary", 
          fitness=knapsack , 
          nBits=n, 
          maxiter=500, # Maximum number of generations 
          run=200,     # Stop if the best-so-far fitness
          # hasn't improved for 'run' generations 
          popSize=200)


# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# see results
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
x.star <- SGA@solution 
# solutions
x.star
# number of elements in each solution
rowSums(x.star) 
# profit in each solution
rowSums(sweep(x.star, MARGIN=2, p, `*`))
# weight of each solution
rowSums(sweep(x.star, MARGIN=2, w, `*`))
```

As for the `GenSA` function, I'm not an expert, but I think it was meant for more complex optimizations, and it minimizes the function (unlike `ga` which maximizes the function), so you can't use the same function for both methods. Another caveat is the fact that the knapsack problem is usually considered a binary problem (choose 0, 1 for nBits), but I'm not sure you can force `GenSA` to do that, so you'll need to find a workaround for that.

Here's my try with `GenSA`, returns a solution with 1456 profit and 750 weight, I used `round` as a workaround to get a binary output

```
library(GenSA)

knapsack_gensa <- function(x) { 
  f <- sum(round(x) * p)
  penalty <- sum(w) * abs(sum(round(x) * w) - W) 
  penalty - f 
}
gensa <- GenSA(lower = rep(0, n), 
               upper = rep(1, n), 
               fn=knapsack_gensa)

solution <- round(gensa$par)
sum(solution)
sum(solution*p)
sum(solution*w)
```